# PHP - Undefined Index na linha 18 sistema de login

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass']; 

    require_once 'connect.php';
    $cons = "SELECT * FROM usuario;";
    $execute = $mysqli->query($cons) or die ($mysqli->error);

    if($execute){
        while($rows = $execute->fetch_assoc()){
            $regist[] = $rows;
        }
    }else{
        $regist=[];
    }
    if($nome === $regist['nome'] && $pass === $regist['senha']){
        if($_POST['continuar']){
            setcookie('nome', $nome, time()+60*60*12);
            setcookie('pass', $pass, time()+60*60*12);
        }
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
    }else{
        $men = "Nome ou Senha incorreto(s)!";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <form method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nome: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="nome">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Senha: </label>
                    <input type="password" name="pass">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Continuar Conectado: </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="continuar">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" name="loga">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual é a linha 18?

Comment: pelo que contei, a linha 18 é `$_POST['continuar']` esse erro indica que a posição do array não existe. Para verificar a existência, faça o seguinte: `if (isset($_POST['continuar'])) {`

Comment: Ja foi resolvido